# How can I start another request after AbortController.abort()?

Tags: asynchronous, httprequest, fetch, abort

I've read about cancelling fetch requests by using [AbortController.abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort). Is there a way to start a request again without aborting it after calling this command?

For example, in [this demo from MDN](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/abort-api/), once *Cancel download* has been clicked, clicking *Download video* will trigger the fetch again, but immediately abort it.

Is there a way to allow this request again without aborting it? So, in this case, how could you click *Download video* to begin the download, click *Cancel download* to cancel the download, and then click *Download video* again to start the download again? For example, if the user clicked *Cancel download* on accident...

Answer (score 28):

You can't.

An `AbortController` or its signal can not be reused nor reseted. If you need to "reset" it, you have to create a new `AbortController` instance and use that instead.

I think this is by design. Otherwise it could get messy e.g. if you hand over the controller or signal to some external library and suddenly they could remotely un-abort your internal state.

Comment: It's idempotent. Often a central part of asynchronous design.

Answer (score 9):

> For example, in this demo from MDN, once Cancel download has been clicked, clicking Download video will trigger the fetch again, but immediately abort it.

They fixed the [example](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/abort-api/index.html). After you click `Cancel download` you will be able to start a new download and cancel it again, over and over. In order to achieve that the `Download button` instantiate a new **AbortController** every time, so you get a fresh signal to abort every time:

```
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchVideo);

function fetchVideo() {
  controller = new AbortController();
  signal = controller.signal;
  // ...
```

So it's ok to instantiate new AbortControllers for each request that you may wish to cancel.

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be kind of late, but I'm leaving this answer anyways in case someone needs it.

I don't know if this is the most optimal approach, but in order to keep doing fetch requests (with 'the same' signal) I had to create a new `AbortController` instance for each request.

In my case (all code being contained inside a class declaration), I deleted and created a new instance every time, like so:

```
class Foo Extends Bar {

    abort_controller_instance = false;

    constructor(params){
        super(params);
        this.resetOrStartAbortController();
    }

    resetOrStartAbortController(){
        if(this.abort_controller_instance){
            delete this.abort_controller_instance;
        }
        this.abort_controller_instance = new AbortController();
    }

    abortFetchRequest(){
        if(this.abort_controller_instance){
            this.abort_controller_instance.abort();
            this.resetOrStartAbortController();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Probably it's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Regards!