# Stopping a Promise with window.stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I'm grabbing json data using `fetch` and rendering list items with the results. The function containing `fetch` is triggered by a button. However, if I click it while the initial `fetch` is still going, data from it will be loaded on top of my new call.

I've used `window.stop()` to halt this behaviour but is there a better solution?

```
function updateTable() {

    fetch('/json')
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((response) => { 
        response.records.forEach(el => {
            return '<li>' + el.Name + '</li>';
        })
    })
}

$('button').click(function(){
    window.stop();
    $('body').empty();
    updateTable()
})
```

**Edited with answer:** Upon re-reading the linked thread on using the new `signal` property with `fetch`, I updated my code to work with the new `AbortController`. The trick, documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091109/how-can-i-start-another-request-after-abortcontroller-abort), is to re-define the controller whenever the function is called again. The advantage vs. `window.stop()` is that stoppage only affects this `fetch`.

```
var controller = "";
var signal = "";

function updateTable() {

  controller = new AbortController();
  signal = controller.signal;

    fetch('/json', {signal})
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((response) => { 
        response.records.forEach(el => {
            return '<li>' + el.Name + '</li>';
        })
    })
}

$('button').click(function(){
    controller.abort();
    $('body').empty();
    updateTable()
})
```

Comment: Disable the button while it's loading, or cancel the pending web request whenever you click the button.

Comment: Answers should not be edited into the question. Instead, mark the correct answer as «accepted». Write your own answer, and mark it as accepted, if you found the solution yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't add a new answer (question is blocked). Why even do all this? I'm sure it'd help others.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a simple variable. That is used to determine if fetch is still processing.

```
var allRecords = [];
var processing = false;

function updateTable() {

    fetch('/json' )
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((response) => { 
        processing = false;
        response.records.forEach(el => {
            return '<li>' + el.Name + '</li>';
        })
    })
}

$('button').click(function(){

    if(processing === false){
        processing = true;
        $('body').empty()
        updateTable()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. However, with a large amount of records, that still means `forEach` will not be stopped immediately.